# How to dynamically set color for back up arrow of search view in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, searchview

In my app, I can dynamically set the color of back up arrow in action bar. But when searchView is expanded, the color of back up arrow changed back to default. I tried to set it back to the correct color by actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrowIconDrawable); but it doesn't make any difference.

I use toolbar as ActionBar in my app.

Comment: This worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904085/how-to-set-the-toolbar-collapseicon-color-programmatically